# Django/Python: CSV for-in loop overriding first row each time through

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views, stringio

```
class CSVDownload(View):
    """ Prepares CSV file version to download """       

        #more code here

        f = StringIO.StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
        for v in visit_list:
            writer.writerow([v.idfa.idfa, v.name, v.duration, v.firstSeen, v.lastSeen, v.identifier, v.closestProximity])
        f.seek(0)
        response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=AdvertiserData.csv'

        return response
```

For some reason, when opening the file in excel, the file will only output the last item in the list, see [image: here]

This leads me to believe that each row is overriding the first row. Although this shouldn't be the case. Look at these tests I have preformed in terminal.

```
>>> f.getvalue()
'FFAC6F6C-1B2E-47C2-8110-5E619B239FB1,PPTest1,00:00:24,2014-11-11 23:20:24.730000,2014-11-11 23:20:48.750000,nkfe-cnb7s,NEAR\r\nFFAC6F6C-1B2E-47C2-8110-5E619B239FB1,moo2,00:00:24,2014-11-11 23:20:24.730000,2014-11-11 23:20:48.750000,nkfe-cnb7s,NEAR\r\n'
```

This returns more than one value, with `\r\n` between the values.

Also, I tried

```
>>> print response
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=boo.csv

FFAC6F6C-1B2E-47C2-8110-5E619B239FB1,PPTest1,00:00:24,2014-11-11 23:20:24.730000,2014-11-11 23:20:48.750000,nkfe-cnb7s,NEAR
FFAC6F6C-1B2E-47C2-8110-5E619B239FB1,moo2,00:00:24,2014-11-11 23:20:24.730000,2014-11-11 23:20:48.750000,nkfe-cnb7s,NEAR
```

And that also showed more than one value.

I saw recently a SO thread here that discusses adding to a file here:[How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python)
But since I am creating this item in memory only (using stringIO), how can I get the same effect?

Thanks!

**EDIT For extra information:**

The `visit_list` is compromised of visit models:

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    idfa = models.ForeignKey(Report) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastSeen = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    firstSeen = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    closestProximity = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Visit"
        verbose_name_plural = "Visits"
```

In this particular case, visit_list returns:

```
>>> visit_list
[<Visit: PPTest1>, <Visit: moo2>]
```

Comment: What does your `visit_list` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bottom Line**: I suspect you need to pass `f.getvalue()` to `HttpResponse` rather than `f`.

**The Explanation**:

[`HttpResponse` prefers strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#usage), although it can also be treated like a file object or accept iterators. Nevertheless, `f` is a `StringIO.StringIO` instance and not a string per se.

Consider the following setup:

```
import StringIO
import csv

>>> f = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
>>> row = range(4)                           # first row is [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(5):
        writer.writerow([row])               # write more rows
        row = [x + 1 for x in row]

>>> f.seek(0)
```

Now compare `f` with the result of `f.getvalue()`:

```
# an instance
>>> f
<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x03656990>

# a string
>>> f.getvalue()
'"[0, 1, 2, 3]"\r\n"[1, 2, 3, 4]"\r\n"[2, 3, 4, 5]"\r\n"[3, 4, 5, 6]"\r\n"[4, 5, 6, 7]"\r\n'
```

Now note the difference in your `response` object when you pass the instance versus the string to `HttpResponse`:

```
# The instance
>>> response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='text/csv')  # f is an instance
>>> response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=AdvertiserData.csv'
>>> response._container
['']

# The string
>>> response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type='text/csv')  # f.getvalue() returns a string
>>> response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=AdvertiserData.csv'
>>> response._container
['"[0, 1, 2, 3]"\r\n"[1, 2, 3, 4]"\r\n"[2, 3, 4, 5]"\r\n"[3, 4, 5, 6]"\r\n"[4, 5 , 6, 7]"\r\n']
```

Note that the response's `_container` attribute is empty when you pass the instance to `HttpResponse` but **not** empty when you pass the `f.getvalue()` string to `HttpResponse`.

I would try this instead, then:

```
>>> response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type='text/csv')
>>> # etc.
```

Comment: Beautiful explanation, and answer worked. Although something interesting happened. I ended up running my old code(returning just f) after running it through a PEP8 check for indentation/tab check, and it seemed to work fine. I am still abit confused about how that happened because it is literally the same code. even github revisions couldn't tell the difference. Nevertheless, your answer works and I think is a better way to return f. Thanks Justin!

Comment: @ApathyBear How interesting. I worked with your code for a while and eventually found these differences. I never received any errors that suggested tabs would be an issue, but that may certainly be the case! In any case, I'm glad you got it working now!